# What is the number of arrangements of all the seven letters of the word “EXAMPLE” in which the vowels are all separated?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

What is the number of arrangements of all the seven letters of the word $EXAMPLE$ in which the vowels are all separated?

I know that $2520$ is the number of arrangements if there are no restrictions. But what I am asking is how many arrangements are there when no two vowels are next to each other. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We first place the letters that are not vowel as,
$$\_X\_M\_P\_L\_$$
Now, we have two $E$'s and one $A$ left and five places to place them. But since $E$'s are identical, we have $\frac{5\cdot4\cdot3}{2} = 30$ ways to place them. We also have $4! = 24$ ways to rearrange the consonant letters so the answer should be $30\cdot24=720$.

Comment: Thank you for your input. But I just don’t understand why you use “5C3/2 = 5 ways”; isn’t the method of finding the number of arrangements a permutation matter, and not a combination matter? I’m not sure, but I think that it should have been 5P3/2 = 30 ways to place them. And so, 30 • 4! = 720. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're right. @ArsenBerk should multiply their result by $3!,$ the number of permutations of three vowels.

Comment: @user10532107 oh, yes you are right. It should be $\frac{5\cdot4\cdot3}{2} =30$. Thank you for the correction.